# Folder Picker .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, .net-6.0, maui-blazor

I want to code a downloader app that saves pictures to a folder. The app should work on windows and mac/os, and maybe later on android and ios.

I haven't found a way to pick the target folder. Any idea on how it can be achieve either with blazor or xaml .NET MAUI app?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've made a start implementing this for Windows and macOS. You can review the code here: https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiFolderPickerSample and wrote a little blog post about this as well here: https://blog.verslu.is/maui/folder-picker-with-dotnet-maui/

This follows kind of the basic pattern you'd want to use if you want to access platform-specific APIs:

- Define an interface
- Implement interface on each supported platform
- Consume functionality

For this I have created a very simple but effective interface

```cs
public interface IFolderPicker
{
    Task<string> PickFolder();
}
```

Then we create an implementation for Windows, by adding a new file `FilePicker.cs` to the `Platforms\Windows\` folder. This makes it specific to Windows and allows us to write Windows specific code. The file contains this code:

```cs
using WindowsFolderPicker = Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker;

namespace MauiFolderPickerSample.Platforms.Windows
{
    public class FolderPicker : IFolderPicker
    {
        public async Task<string> PickFolder()
        {
            var folderPicker = new WindowsFolderPicker();
            // Make it work for Windows 10
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
            // Get the current window's HWND by passing in the Window object
            var hwnd = ((MauiWinUIWindow)App.Current.Windows[0].Handler.PlatformView).WindowHandle;

            // Associate the HWND with the file picker
            WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(folderPicker, hwnd);

            var result = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

            return result.Path;
        }
    }
}
```

Because I chose `FolderPicker` as the name for my own object here, there is a naming conflict with the Windows `FolderPicker` that is why there is that weird using at the top. If you go for `MyFolderPicker` as your object name that wouldn't be needed.

Now we register this interface and implementation with the generic host builder in our `MauiProgram.cs`:

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

// Note: this part was added

#if WINDOWS
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IFolderPicker, Platforms.Windows.FolderPicker>();
#elif MACCATALYST
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IFolderPicker, Platforms.MacCatalyst.FolderPicker>();
#endif
        builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<App>();
// Note: end added part

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Note that I also added `MainPage` and `App` here so that our constructor injection works (have a look at `MainPage.xaml.cs` in the linked repository).

Now we can consume our functionality as follows:

```cs
namespace MauiFolderPickerSample;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly IFolderPicker _folderPicker;

    public MainPage(IFolderPicker folderPicker)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _folderPicker = folderPicker;
    }

    private async void OnPickFolderClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pickedFolder = await _folderPicker.PickFolder();

        FolderLabel.Text = pickedFolder;

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(FolderLabel.Text);
    }
}
```

Implementing other platforms would require you to implement the interface for the platform you want to support and register it in the generic host builder. This should get you started for Windows and macOS.

Actually calling this should not be any different between .NET MAUI (regular) or .NET MAUI Blazor.

Comment: Hey Gerald, from testing this solution it seems that while this is working on windows 11, on windows 10 it returns the following error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'

I've tested on multiple machines with your demo project and 11 works and 10 always throws that error.  Here's a bug report that we created for maui:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5443

Comment: After further testing we eventually figured out that the issue on windows 10 can be resolved from adding the following to the windows platform code:

folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

Comment: Hi Gerald. I'm looking for a folder picker for a small oss project. I noticed that your sample has no specific licence, and I wondered if you'd be happy to licence it for others to use?

Comment: @AndyJohnson This applies to all of Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thanks for this. I implemented your solution for Mac Catalyst. 
When I can choose a folder, it returns a path as follows: 
file:///Users/macminim1/Documents/Sorted%20Testing/
 if I use System.IO.Directory.Exists(pickedFolder))
right after choosing the folder, the above returns false. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @GeraldVersluis, are there any plans to make FolderPicker work in Android and iOS too? Thank you!

Comment: There is some discussion on that here: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/discussions/381 make sure to make your voice heard!

Comment: There is a small issue with this, at least on Windows. When the picker dialog initially appears, the "Ok" button is disabled. So in order to select the initial directory, the user must navigate out, then return to the directory, in order for the "Ok" button to become clickable.

Comment: Hi Gerald, is something similar possible with Android and iOS?

Comment: Hi all, I'm pretty new in MAUI and I'm trying to implement the folder picker in a .NET MAUI class library. I implemented the interface as in your project and the two FolderPicker.cs files for Windows and Mac platforms. But in the FolderPicker.cs related to the Windows platform, the line `var hwnd = ((MauiWinUIWindow)App.Current.Windows[0].Handler.PlatformView).WindowHandle;` gives me an error because _App_ doesn't exist in that context. How can I manage it?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, I just hit this issue on MacCatalyst with the path starting with "file", if I manually remove the "file" but, it works with System.IO.Directory.Exists() I will try that in other operations but have found any comments/fixes for this.

Comment: Thanks for the example, especially the WinRT.Interop part. I like it that this solution doesn't need any privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, .NET Maui now has a folder selector plugin. Ok, so the NuGet package does more than just picking folders, but that's for a different question

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/essentials/folder-picker?tabs=android

The .NET MAUI Community Toolkit ([CommunityToolkit.Maui](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui) in NuGet) gives you a folder picker that's pretty easy to use and set up.

iOS and Windows don't need any permissions, but Android does, if you don't already have this set up. Open the Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following in the manifest node:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then include the following code wherever you need it:

```
async Task PickFolder(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await FolderPicker.Default.PickAsync(cancellationToken);
    if (result.IsSuccessful)
    {
        await Toast.Make($"The folder was picked: Name - {result.Folder.Name}, Path - {result.Folder.Path}", ToastDuration.Long).Show(cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        await Toast.Make($"The folder was not picked with error: {result.Exception.Message}").Show(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Or you can make it into a button click event like I did:

```
private async void PickFolder_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new();
    CancellationToken token = source.Token;
    var result = await FolderPicker.Default.PickAsync(token);
    
    if (result.IsSuccessful)
    {
        SaveLocation.Text = result.Folder.Path; // SaveLocation is a textbox in my XAML file
    }
}
```

Just make sure to use the `CommunityToolkit` package for the `FolderPicker`, instead of the `Windows` library VS 2022 auto-populated for me.

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage;
```

You will also need to add the [Community Toolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui) to your startup class.

```
builder
    ...
    .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
```

So far, I have it working fine in Android, but I haven't tested it in anything else. YMMV.

Comment: What is the NuGet package?
When I search for `CommunitToolkit` I get this which seems to be wrong. https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet

Comment: @RichardBarraclough, you were close, but no, that's not the correct package. https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui I'll update my answer.