# Is there a dialog for saving files in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui

.NET MAUI provides a FilePicker to show a native Dialog where you can pick a file from the device.

Is there a way to show a dialog for saving files? (where you can select a path and enter an filename, ...).

I didn't find anything in the .NET MAUI doc and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70999773/folder-picker-net-maui) StackOverflow question to implement a FolderPicker, but this is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now there is no such thing, not that I know of anyway. We are considering adding something like that to the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit, you can find the discussion and even some implementation details [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/discussions/381). Make sure to make your interest known there.

With the linked Stack Overflow question you should be well on your well to build something yourself as well, at least for Windows and macOS.

Answer (score 4):

The .Net Maui community toolkit (https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui)

now has FilePicker (for choosing files) and FileSaver (for choosing a location to be saved) dialogs/controls

FileSaver info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/essentials/file-saver?tabs=windows

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbuo3.png)