# Why does System.IO.Directory.Exists return false when viewing Mac path in .net Maui?

Tags: .net-maui

I am building a .net Maui app which targets Mac Catalyst.
I implemented a folder picker from @GeraldVersluis

[Folder Picker .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70999773/folder-picker-net-maui)

When choosing the folder the following path is returned:
pickedFolder = file:///Users/macminim1/Documents/Sorted%20Testing/

If I then use:

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(pickedFolder))
{

}
```

The result is false.
Obviously, the folder exists as I just chose it and I confirmed it's existence in the file system.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could direct to this folder in the Terminal and use the 'pwd' command, this should return you the correct path. I think 'file:://' is not correct

Comment: Thanks that helped. You were correct, the file:/ part needs to be removed. Also the path needs to be unescaped.